# Are there any open source firewalls for a VPN server?

Tags: network, firewalls, vpn

I provide free VPN access to a lot of people and often times have troubles dealing with abuse reports from stupid stuff like network scanning.

I have been researching for hours now, but I am astonished that I can't find any open-source solution which is able to detect and block such traffic bi-directionally (mostly outbound though is what I care about).

Hopefully, there is something great out there that I just can't find for some reason.

Kind Regards,

Nick

Comment: why doesn't iptables meet your needs?

Comment: also, I don't think you want a firewall but an IDS - you want to block how traffic is used based on content, not the state of the traffic

Answer (score 2):

Did you try pfsense ?

https://www.pfsense.org/

I implemented it into few companies infrastructure via small appliance.
(you can also DL the iso and install it on your own hardware)

Powerfull, flexible and opensource. I strongly recommend it.

Comment: Hmm, I looked into it, but the problem is that I need something that I can install onto a VPS running debian for example.

Comment: This VPN won't run on any local hardware or networks that I have full control of. The solution needs to operate within my Debian environment.

Comment: Iptables or packet filter wont do the trick ?